# express 4.0 body-parser is not visible to route handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to put via Google POSTMAN as follows

```
PUT /updateUser/bbb@sss.com HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3f1e9857-302a-f4cf-4c24-d3222b4bc292

{"email":"bbb@sss.com", "pass":"kkk"}
```

When I debug the req.body is undefined. Here is my code
server.js

```
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , models = require('./models')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , routes = require('./controllers')
    , user = require('./controllers/users.js')
    , port = 8081 //process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/', user);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

module.exports = app;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/m101JS', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("mongoose connected")
    //routes(app);
    var server = app.listen(port, function () {
        var host = server.address().address
        var port = server.address().port
        console.log("RESTful Web Services listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
    })
})
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express')
    , router = express.Router()
    , mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , User = mongoose.model('User')
    , crypto = require('crypto')
    , cleanString = require('../helpers/cleanString')
    , hash = require('../helpers/hash');
// ......    
// Update user
router.put('/updateUser/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var email = cleanString(req.body.email);
    var pass = cleanString(req.body.pass);
    if (!(email && pass)) {
        return invalid(email);
    }

    crypto.randomBytes(16, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        var user = { _id: email };
        user.salt = bytes.toString('utf8');
        user.hash = hash(pass, user.salt);

        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, user, function (err, post) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json("updated:" + post);
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

It used to work when not using the router class like 
old server.js

```
//....
routes(app);
```

old users.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.put('/updateUser/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    .....
}
```

So how can I fix the current code to make body-parser visible to the users.js? I mean not having to require it in every file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of configuring middlewares is important in express js. In your configuration, you have specified router mapping first followed by the body parser middle ware. All you need to do is configure body parser first followed by router mapping.

for exp:

```
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use('/', routes);
  app.use('/', user);
```

Comment: Thank you Nalla, that worked perfectly. Very much appreciate your help.